# Materials pink in new version of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I build assetbundles in unity 5.2. I load its assetbundles in scene in new version of Unity 5.3 - then all materials became pink (even if shaders in Standard) http://prntscr.com/ampdr3. If I set again shader Standard - its ok became.

in Editor log I got errors:
GpuProgram creation error: shader program type is unrecognised. You might have a precompiled shader asset from an old Unity version.

WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD_DELTA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'SHADOWCASTER' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - All passes removed
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'FORWARD_DELTA' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - Pass 'SHADOWCASTER' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Standard' - All passes removed

Comment: Asking more questions without accepting any old answers....

Comment: @Programmer, really? If so I wont give my answer as I know one - I had similar problem.

Comment: That's  fine now. When people help you, you accept the answer if solved your problem. I am trying to figure out what your problem is. Will be back if I am able replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bundle was build with 5.2 you should rebuild it in 5.3 to use it in this version. It is not always true, and sometimes you can use bundle from previous version in new one. We had similar problems in our company, when some people have change their version of unity and others did not. Now one person dictates if we update or not, and we rebuild our bundles after updates.